# How Do I Check Convexity Using The Actual Definition?

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^{+}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is defined as follows:
\begin{eqnarray}
f(u)=\text{sgn}(\rho)\left(u^{\rho+1}-1\right),~u\geq 0,
\end{eqnarray}
where $\rho\in (-1,\infty)$, $\rho\neq 0$, is a fixed parameter. I need to show that $f$, as defined above, is convex on its domain. It is true that
\begin{eqnarray}
f''(u)=\rho(\rho+1)\text{sgn}(\rho)u^{\rho}\geq 0
\end{eqnarray}
for all values of $u\geq 0$ since $\rho>-1$ and $\rho(\text{sgn}(\rho))\geq 0$. This could serve as a means to show that $f$ is convex, but I would like to show the same from first principles, i.e., I would like to show:

Given any $u,v\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and any $\alpha \in [0,1]$, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
f(\alpha u+(1-\alpha)v)\leq \alpha f(u)+(1-\alpha)f(v).
\end{eqnarray}

In other words, I am looking for a proof of convexity of the function $g(x)=x^{\rho},~x\geq 0, ~\rho\geq 1$, using the above definition.

Can someone please guide me on how to do this? Any useful inequalities that I may need?

Comment: It depends. You can use a second-order Taylor expansion of $f$ at $\alpha \, u + (1-\alpha) \, v$, but this boils down to $f'' \ge 0$ everywhere.

Comment: @gerw My only concern in sticking to the approach of proving convexity using the definition is to be able to address functions which are not differentiable at some points in the domain.

Comment: It is usually impractical to use the first principle methods. In some cases like the exponential function, it works because of AMGM inequality. But even in simple cases like $f(x)=x^2$, the difficulty ramps up.

Comment: Hmm.. I see.. Thank you @GautamShenoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happened to find the solution to the question I asked during a discussion with my professor yesterday. Turns out, the inequality that I am after is a special case of the Holder's inequality. I am posting the solution here for the benefit of the community at large.

The following is the proof of convexity of the function $f(x)=x^{\rho},~\rho>1,~x\geq 0$. Suppose $\Omega=\{1,2\}$. Let $X$ and $Y$ be two real-valued random variables defined on $\Omega$ as follows:
\begin{eqnarray}
X(1)=u,~X(2)=v,~ u,v\in \mathbb{R}_{+}\\
Y(1)=1,~Y(2)=1.
\end{eqnarray}

Let $\mathbb{P}$ be a probability measure defined on the $\sigma$-algebra of the subsets of $\Omega$ such that $\mathbb{P}(1)=\alpha$ and $\mathbb{P}(2)=1-\alpha$, for some $0\leq \alpha\leq 1$. Then, applying Holder's inequality to $L^{\rho}(\mathbb{P})$, we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{\Omega}XYd\mathbb{P} \leq \left(\int_{\Omega} X^{\rho}d\mathbb{P}\right)^{1/\rho} \left(\int_{\Omega} Y^{\frac{\rho}{\rho-1}}d\mathbb{P}\right)^{\frac{\rho-1}{\rho}}\\
\Rightarrow \left(\alpha u+(1-\alpha) v\right) \leq \left(\alpha u^{\rho}+(1-\alpha) v^{\rho}\right)^{1/\rho}\\
\Rightarrow \left(\alpha u+(1-\alpha) v\right)^{\rho} \leq \left(\alpha u^{\rho}+(1-\alpha) v^{\rho}\right),
\end{eqnarray}
which was the inequality desired.